# Count no IReport

Tags: mysql, sql, ireport

Tenho um relatório onde tenho a coluna `Status`, nessa coluna tenho os seguintes status: Finalizado e Pendente.

Criei uma variável e adicionei ela na banda `Sumary` e configurei as seguintes propriedades:

```
Variable class = java.lang.Integer
Calculation = Sum
ResetType = Report
Increment type = None
Variable expression = $F{tbl_suspensao_status}.equals("Finalizado")  ? 0 : 1
```

Porém o resultado é sempre o total tudo, seu eu tenho 2 Finalizados e 2 Pendentes o resultado fica igual a 4.

Como posso contar corretamente quantos Status são Finalizados e quantos são Pendentes?

---

Query:

```
SELECT
     tbl_suspensao.`codigoBeneficiario` AS tbl_suspensao_codigoBeneficiario,
     tbl_suspensao.`contrato` AS tbl_suspensao_contrato,
     tbl_suspensao.`data_fim` AS tbl_suspensao_data_fim,
     tbl_suspensao.`data_inicio` AS tbl_suspensao_data_inicio,
     tbl_suspensao.`status` AS tbl_suspensao_status,
     tbl_usuario.`nome` AS tbl_usuario_nome,
     tbl_suspensao.`nomeBeneficiario` AS tbl_suspensao_nomeBeneficiario
FROM
     `tbl_usuario` tbl_usuario INNER JOIN `tbl_suspensao` tbl_suspensao ON tbl_usuario.`codigo` = tbl_suspensao.`usuario_id`
WHERE
 AND tbl_suspensao.`data_inicio` BETWEEN  $P{Data_Inicio} AND $P{Data_Fim}

GROUP BY
      tbl_suspensao_status
```

Comment: Tem que fazer ou `groupBy` por Status.

Comment: Aonde eu coloco esse groupBy? Na query?

Comment: Isso mesmo. `Select Status, Count(Id) as Total From Tabela Group By Status`

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, coloquei o group By no final, além de não mostrar todos os registros no relatório também não conta os totais

Comment: Como você está montando a query ? Coloca ela no tópico.

Comment: Pronto, coloquei

Comment: O `GROUP BY` funciona assim... O que você colocar no `SELECT` tem que colocar no `GROUP BY`. Mas se os dados do `SELECT` forem diferentes, sua contagem não vai ser exata. Eu sugiro que você faça apenas um `SELECT` para a contagem. Bem simples. `SELECT Status, Count(tbl_usuarios.nome) as Total Group By Status`. Ou seja, vão ter duas query no seu iReport. Uma para os registros e uma para o total. Mas eu não lembro se o iReport tem a função que já pega o total de registros. Não tem ?

Comment: Acho que a função `Count` faz isso

Comment: Também não sei como colocar duas querys no mesmo relatório

Comment: @Techies, tente fazer isso `Select Coluna,count(*) from Tabela group by Coluna`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

coloca uma coluna para fazer a contagem tipo assim:

```
    SELECT
     sum(1) as contador,
     tbl_suspensao.`codigoBeneficiario` AS tbl_suspensao_codigoBeneficiario,
     tbl_suspensao.`contrato` AS tbl_suspensao_contrato,
     tbl_suspensao.`data_fim` AS tbl_suspensao_data_fim,
     tbl_suspensao.`data_inicio` AS tbl_suspensao_data_inicio,
     tbl_suspensao.`status` AS tbl_suspensao_status,
     tbl_usuario.`nome` AS tbl_usuario_nome,
     tbl_suspensao.`nomeBeneficiario` AS tbl_suspensao_nomeBeneficiario
FROM
     `tbl_usuario` tbl_usuario INNER JOIN `tbl_suspensao` tbl_suspensao ON tbl_usuario.`codigo` = tbl_suspensao.`usuario_id`
WHERE
 AND tbl_suspensao.`data_inicio` BETWEEN  $P{Data_Inicio} AND $P{Data_Fim}

GROUP BY
      tbl_suspensao_status;
```

Assim a coluna **contador** fica sendo seu **Field** lá no iReport.

Comment: Obrigado @NinjA